# Change name of Resteasy generated <collection> element to something else?

Tags: collections, jaxb, jax-rs, resteasy

```
<collection>
<Car>
<Car>
<Car>
</collection>
```

I would like to change the name of the  tag to 
I have no idea what I'm using--it's just Jboss 7.1.1 and a standard multimodule EAR maven setup.  I should have RESTEasy included, with whatever JAXB provider they use.

@XmlElementWrapper annotation I have access to, but it does not work when I annotate the JAXRS service method "getCars".  It has no effect on the xml output.

@Wrapped(element="cars") doesn't work b/c I can not seem to import the RESTEasy jax-rs jar.  I added it into my pom.xml but it's not being picked up.
1) no idea if "jboss having RESTEasy included" means that I shouldn't even need to worry about importing another library just so that I can use the @Wrapped annotation.
2) Can I get by with the @XmlElementWrapper annotation for my purposes?

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Path("/")
@XmlElementWrapper(name="cars")//I have access to this annotation but nothing happens
@Wrapped(element="cars")//eclipse doesn't know what this annotation means
public List<car> getCars();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by using the `@Wrapped` annotation.

To get this annotation into your project, try to add this artifact to your `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Another option is to create your own wrapper class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="cars")
public class CarCollection {
    @XmlElement(name="car")
    private List<Car> articles = new ArrayList<Car>();
}

@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Path("/")
public CarCollection getCars();
```

Using just the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation won't work.

Comment: Thank you for telling me this.  I tried it and it did NOT work.  BUT, knowing Eclipse and its very buggy maven integration, I started cleaning the project, and ended up nuking it in all ways from the command line. I did not touch my source code at all. Removing eclipse out of the equation, and then of course my project compiled and it works.  (I had previously added the maven dependency you list, but it didn't seem to be recognized).

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it to to work. I used to develop with eclipse too, and had lots of issues similar to the problem you describe. But after I switched to IntelliJ, I've never looked back :)

Comment: Really? Wow, I have never enjoyed Eclipse, but it is the 800 lb gorilla in the room.  There must be a reason why Google switched to IntelliJ for Android development (Android Studio)...this may be confirmation of what I've suspected all along--Eclipse, thank you for being free, a valiant effort, but I've lost way too many hours b/c of bugs that are in Eclipse.  I make enough errors on my own, I don't need my IDE to do the same.  If the 8000 lb Google Gorilla is switching to IntelliJ, maybe I will too.

Comment: @user798719 Preach